# caffe segnet deep observation wrong batch layer parameters

Tags: caffe

I created a caffe model on top of segnet/deepobservationEO
I compiled caffe successfully. I used the model proposed here: 
https://github.com/nshaud/DeepNetsForEO/blob/master/models/segnet_isprs_vaihingen_irrg.prototxt

I get that issue:

```
....
I0221 05:26:39.852553 1508 net.cpp:408] conv1_1 <- data
I0221 05:26:39.852568 1508 net.cpp:382] conv1_1 -> conv1_1
I0221 05:26:39.855118 1508 net.cpp:124] Setting up conv1_1
I0221 05:26:39.855144 1508 net.cpp:131] Top shape: 10 64 128 128 (10485760)
I0221 05:26:39.855150 1508 net.cpp:139] Memory required for data: 45875200
I0221 05:26:39.855170 1508 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1_1_bn
I0221 05:26:39.856801 1508 net.cpp:86] Creating Layer conv1_1_bn
I0221 05:26:39.856830 1508 net.cpp:408] conv1_1_bn <- conv1_1
I0221 05:26:39.856847 1508 net.cpp:369] conv1_1_bn -> conv1_1 (in-place)
F0221 05:26:39.856976 1508 batch_norm_layer.cpp:44] Check failed: this->     layer_param_.param(i).lr_mult() == 0.f (0.5 vs. 0) Cannot configure batch normalization statistics as layer parameters.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

any idea about what to do, where to check?
thx
colin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have `lr_mult: 0.5` for layer `conv1_1_bn` of type `"BatchNorm"`.
Caffe only supports `lr_mult: 0` for layer `"BatchNorm"`.